# How can I correct this MySQL database set up?

Tags: mysql

One of my MySQL databases is currently using over 99% CPU when running PHP/[Drupal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) queries.

I am investigating what the root cause is.

Using the following profiling and configuration data, can you suggest a main database setup problems or missing/incorrect configuration?

Output of [`free`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/free) in Bash:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048       1635        412          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1635        412
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Output of `ps auxf`:

```
root      7430  0.0  0.0   9176  1400 ?        S    May30   0:00
/bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/db.pid
mysql     7617  0.6 12.3 486900 258956 ?       Sl   May30 114:26  \_ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/db.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/db.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Here is the `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
local-infile=0
tmpdir=/dev/shm
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

Here is the output of `sql show status`:

```
SQL result

Host: localhost
Database: db
Generation Time: Jun 11, 2012 at 09:22 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.4.7.1 / MySQL 5.5.24
SQL query: SHOW STATUS;
Rows: 310

Variable_name    Value
Aborted_clients    242
Aborted_connects    50
Binlog_cache_disk_use    0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use    0
Bytes_received    221
Bytes_sent    1421
Com_admin_commands    0
Com_assign_to_keycache    0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event    0
Com_alter_function    0
Com_alter_procedure    0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table    0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_analyze    0
Com_begin    0
Com_binlog    0
Com_call_procedure    0
Com_change_db    1
Com_change_master    0
Com_check    0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit    0
Com_create_db    0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function    0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server    0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger    0
Com_create_udf    0
Com_create_user    0
Com_create_view    0
Com_dealloc_sql    0
Com_delete    0
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do    0
Com_drop_db    0
Com_drop_event    0
Com_drop_function    0
Com_drop_index    0
Com_drop_procedure    0
Com_drop_server    0
Com_drop_table    0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user    0
Com_drop_view    0
Com_empty_query    0
Com_execute_sql    0
Com_flush    0
Com_grant    0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open    0
Com_ha_read    0
Com_help    0
Com_insert    0
Com_insert_select    0
Com_install_plugin    0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables    0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql    0
Com_purge    0
Com_purge_before_date    0
Com_release_savepoint    0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user    0
Com_repair    0
Com_replace    0
Com_replace_select    0
Com_reset    0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke    0
Com_revoke_all    0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint    0
Com_savepoint    0
Com_select    0
Com_set_option    2
Com_signal    0
Com_show_authors    0
Com_show_binlog_events    0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets    0
Com_show_collations    0
Com_show_contributors    0
Com_show_create_db    0
Com_show_create_event    0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table    0
Com_show_create_trigger    0
Com_show_databases    0
Variable_name     Value
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex    0
Com_show_engine_status    0
Com_show_events    0
Com_show_errors    0
Com_show_fields    0
Com_show_function_status    0
Com_show_grants    0
Com_show_keys    0
Com_show_master_status    0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    1
Com_show_privileges    0
Com_show_procedure_status    0
Com_show_processlist    0
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles    0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status    0
Com_show_status    1
Com_show_storage_engines    0
Com_show_table_status    0
Com_show_tables    0
Com_show_triggers    0
Com_show_variables    0
Com_show_warnings    0
Com_slave_start    0
Com_slave_stop    0
Com_stmt_close    0
Com_stmt_execute    0
Com_stmt_fetch    0
Com_stmt_prepare    0
Com_stmt_reprepare    0
Com_stmt_reset    0
Com_stmt_send_long_data    0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables    0
Com_update    0
Com_update_multi    0
Com_xa_commit    0
Com_xa_end    0
Com_xa_prepare    0
Com_xa_recover    0
Com_xa_rollback    0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression    OFF
Connections    9376
Created_tmp_disk_tables    1
Created_tmp_files    6
Created_tmp_tables    1
Delayed_errors    0
Delayed_insert_threads    0
Delayed_writes    0
Flush_commands    1
Handler_commit    0
Handler_delete    0
Handler_discover    0
Handler_prepare    0
Handler_read_first    0
Handler_read_key    0
Handler_read_last    0
Handler_read_next    0
Handler_read_prev    0
Handler_read_rnd    0
Handler_read_rnd_next    21
Handler_rollback    0
Handler_savepoint    0
Handler_savepoint_rollback    0
Handler_update    0
Handler_write    20
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data    8142
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    1269726
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc    49
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total    8191
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead    1306
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    8907
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    139892912
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    308579
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests    5066182
Innodb_data_fsyncs    313257
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_data_pending_reads    0
Innodb_data_pending_writes    0
Innodb_data_read    5084336128
Innodb_data_reads    308981
Innodb_data_writes    658963
Innodb_data_written    22884830208
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written    634863
Innodb_dblwr_writes    19355
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins    ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests    3971026
Innodb_log_writes    266658
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    273603
Variable_name     Value
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written    2077984256
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    55793
Innodb_pages_read    310189
Innodb_pages_written    634863
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits    0
Innodb_row_lock_time    185765
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    476
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    30082
Innodb_row_lock_waits    390
Innodb_rows_deleted    96261
Innodb_rows_inserted    243234
Innodb_rows_read    73669737
Innodb_rows_updated    367966
Innodb_truncated_status_writes    0
Key_blocks_not_flushed    0
Key_blocks_unused    6657
Key_blocks_used    851
Key_read_requests    33873766
Key_reads    3991
Key_write_requests    5515715
Key_writes    11500
Last_query_cost    2.399000
Max_used_connections    22
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files    41
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions    400
Open_tables    400
Opened_files    141222
Opened_table_definitions    0
Opened_tables    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_locker_lost    0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Prepared_stmt_count    0
Qcache_free_blocks    0
Qcache_free_memory    0
Qcache_hits    0
Qcache_inserts    0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached    0
Qcache_queries_in_cache    0
Qcache_total_blocks    0
Queries    4346053
Questions    5
Rpl_status    AUTH_MASTER
Select_full_join    0
Select_full_range_join    0
Select_range    0
Select_range_check    0
Select_scan    1
Slave_heartbeat_period    0.000
Slave_open_temp_tables    0
Slave_received_heartbeats    0
Slave_retried_transactions    0
Slave_running    OFF
Slow_launch_threads    0
Slow_queries    0
Sort_merge_passes    0
Sort_range    0
Sort_rows    0
Sort_scan    0
Ssl_accept_renegotiates    0
Ssl_accepts    0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits    0
Ssl_cipher
Ssl_cipher_list
Ssl_client_connects    0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode    0
Ssl_default_timeout    0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects    0
Ssl_session_cache_hits    0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode    NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows    0
Ssl_session_cache_size    0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts    0
Ssl_sessions_reused    0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries    0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode    0
Ssl_version
Table_locks_immediate    5113600
Variable_name     Value
Table_locks_waited    17
Tc_log_max_pages_used    0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits    0
Threads_cached    0
Threads_connected    1
Threads_created    9375
Threads_running    1
Uptime    1074227
Uptime_since_flush_status    1074227
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also examine carefully which queries are performed and on what tables. I don't know if Drupal has some kind of debugging/profiling mode for queries, but it's worth a try to investigate this.

From these, also trying to examine them with EXPLAIN (for example, some tables may need indexes).

I understand your site is in Drupal, which should be already optimized at least on its core tables.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, one of the bottlenecks was a custom sql query (Drupal view) with over 13 LEFT JOINS. However my main concern here is if the MySQL configuration above is correct. Should it be  optimized and how?

Comment: I'm really sorry but my knowledge of configuration issues is not so complete. Better ask someone else, I would not want to give you unuseful or misleading information.
That said, in my experience, most of these high CPU loads can easily be solved by rewriting the queries or organizing them in a better way.